# Java error saving xml

Tags: java, xml, dom, save

I have a Document object in java and I want to save it, so I have this code:

```
TransformerFactory fabTransformador = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformador = fabTransformador.newTransformer();

Source origin = new DOMSource(documentoXML);

Result destino = new StreamResult(new java.io.File(nombrearchivo));

transformador.transform(origin, destino);
```

where "nombrearchivo" is the file name (file.xml) and `documentoXML`is the Document object.
When I execute the code, I receive as output: ERROR:  ''
I don't receive any exception, just the message ERROR:  ''
The document is about 1,3 GB, I don't know it it is the problem, and in that case, is there another way to save the file?

I use the next imports:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
```

Comment: Code looks fine.  What do your `catch` block(s) contain?

Comment: Did you test your logic on small documents?

Comment: Could you show us the output from running the code?

Comment: @VGR catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) and catch (TransformerException ex)

Comment: @timonik, I don't have that problem with small documents, that's wh I think the problem is the size of the document, but I don't receive any exception, just the message ERROR: ""

Comment: @bmorris591, the output is just ERROR: ""

Comment: what code you have in catch block (just copy it as-is to question)?

Comment: try {
                        
                        secure.generaTextoXML();
                    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

Comment: generaTextoXML is the function that I post on the message

Comment: Can you provide info about your logger (what library and configuration you use)?

Comment: what version of java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but for reference there's an alternative approach you can use for saving a DOM document:

```
import org.w3c.dom.ls.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS)documentoXML.getImplementation();
LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
LSOutput out = ls.createLSOutput();
out.setEncoding("UTF-8");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("output.xml");
try {
  out.setByteStream(output);
  ser.write(documentoXML, out);
} finally {
  output.close();
}
```

Comment: I have used your code instead mine, but it reports me a java.net.UnknownHostException: file

Comment: That UnknownHostException is often caused by a file URL which has two slashes after the scheme (`file:`).  You must have either one slash or three slashes after `file:`.

Comment: But I get the exception with out.setSystemId("output.xml"); Maybe I have to write the whole url?

Comment: @user2083473 I've edited the answer to use a `FileOutputStream` directly, which should bypass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to determine exact reason:

```
try { 
 secure.generaTextoXML(); 
} catch (Trowable thr) { 
 thr.printStackTrace();
}
```

... or try `Level.ERROR` instead of `Level.SEVERE` for your logger:

```
try { 
 secure.generaTextoXML(); 
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.ERROR, null, ex); 
} catch (TransformerException ex) { 
 Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.ERROR, null, ex); 
}
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and I get javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:736) any idea? Thanks

Comment: Could you put whole stack trace in question?